# Failed to load JVM DLL. As i have already declared JAVA_HOME Variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, java-11

As i have declared java_home in environment variables if i start android studio electric ele its showing the message failed to load jvm dll. I am using latest version of android studio.
Here is the screen shot as if i open android studio i am getting
[If i open android studio as normal and also as administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SJ8z.png)
Here is the screenshot as i have declared java home variable
[Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siU4c.png)

May i know how to resolve the issue

- i have tried by deleting AndroidStudio\jbr\bin\server\jvm.dll ----But its Not Worked
- i have tried with jdk latest version ----- Its Showing same error
- i have tried with jdk8 ---------Its also showing same error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue with Electric eel. Downgraded to Dolphin.